# Can't resolve "re-base" react.js + firebase, error installing re-base

Tags: reactjs, firebase, redux

I'm trying to link my firebase on my react.js app (I also use Redux).
I installed react-rebase and in my file base.js I'm trying to import Rebase from 're-base' (as in the doc https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-rebase). But, when I start my app, I have this error "Can't resolve 're-base'" and I don't understand why...
Could you help me please ?

Thanks and sorry for English mistakes

edit : when I tried to install directly re-base, I have errors and this is the debug.log

```
node-pre-gyp ERR! Pre-built binaries not installable for grpc@1.10.1 and node@8.9.4 (node-v57 ABI, unknown) (falling back to source compile with node-gyp) 
node-pre-gyp ERR! Hit error self signed certificate in certificate chain
gyp ERR! configure error
gyp ERR! stack Error: Can't find Python executable "python", you can set the PYTHON env variable.
gyp ERR! stack     at PythonFinder.failNoPython (C:\Users\username\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\configure.js:483:19)
gyp ERR! stack     at PythonFinder.<anonymous> (C:\Users\username\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\configure.js:508:16)
gyp ERR! stack     at C:\Users\username\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\graceful-fs\polyfills.js:284:29
gyp ERR! stack     at FSReqWrap.oncomplete (fs.js:152:21)
gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 10.0.16299
gyp ERR! command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\User\\username\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\npm\\node_modules\\npm-lifecycle\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js" "configure" "--fallback-to-build" "--library=static_library" "--module=C:\\Users\\username\\node_modules\\grpc\\src\\node\\extension_binary\\node-v57-win32-x64-unknown\\grpc_node.node" "--module_name=grpc_node" "--module_path=C:\\Users\\username\\node_modules\\grpc\\src\\node\\extension_binary\\node-v57-win32-x64-unknown"
gyp ERR! cwd C:\Users\username\node_modules\grpc
gyp ERR! node -v v8.9.4
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.6.2
gyp ERR! not ok
node-pre-gyp ERR! build error
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack Error: Failed to execute 'C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe C:\Users\username\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js configure --fallback-to-build --library=static_library --module=C:\Users\username\node_modules\grpc\src\node\extension_binary\node-v57-win32-x64-unknown\grpc_node.node --module_name=grpc_node --module_path=C:\Users\username\node_modules\grpc\src\node\extension_binary\node-v57-win32-x64-unknown' (1)
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (C:\Users\username\node_modules\grpc\node_modules\node-pre-gyp\lib\util\compile.js:83:29)
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at emitTwo (events.js:126:13)
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:214:7)
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:925:16)
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:209:5)
node-pre-gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 10.0.16299
node-pre-gyp ERR! command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Users\\username\\node_modules\\grpc\\node_modules\\node-pre-gyp\\bin\\node-pre-gyp" "install" "--fallback-to-build" "--library=static_library"
node-pre-gyp ERR! cwd C:\Users\username\node_modules\grpc
node-pre-gyp ERR! node -v v8.9.4
node-pre-gyp ERR! node-pre-gyp -v v0.7.0
node-pre-gyp ERR! not ok
Failed to execute 'C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe C:\Users\username\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js configure --fallback-to-build --library=static_library --module=C:\Users\username\node_modules\grpc\src\node\extension_binary\node-v57-win32-x64-unknown\grpc_node.node --module_name=grpc_node --module_path=C:\Users\username\node_modules\grpc\src\node\extension_binary\node-v57-win32-x64-unknown' (1)
npm WARN enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Users\username\package.json'
npm WARN react-router@4.2.0 requires a peer of react@>=15 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN react-router-dom@4.2.2 requires a peer of react@>=15 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN @firebase/firestore@0.3.7 requires a peer of @firebase/app@^0.1.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN @firebase/firestore@0.3.7 requires a peer of @firebase/app-types@^0.1.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN @firebase/firestore-types@0.2.2 requires a peer of @firebase/app-types@^0.1.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN username No description
npm WARN username No repository field.
npm WARN username No README data
npm WARN username No license field.
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! grpc@1.10.1 install: `node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build --library=static_library`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the grpc@1.10.1 install script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\username\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2018-03-31T17_26_29_575Z-debug.log
```